# Groupwise downsampling and plotting of pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I am trying to downsample grouped data to daily averages, calculated for each group, and plot the resulting time series in a single plot.
My starting point is the following `pd.DataFrame`:

```
value        time       type
0.1234       2013-04-03 A
0.2345       2013-04-05 A
0.34564      2013-04-07 A
...          ...      ...
0.2345       2013-04-03 B
0.1234       2013-04-05 B
0.2345       2013-04-07 C
0.34564      2013-04-07 C
```

I would like to calculate daily means for each type of content, and plot the time series of these daily means in a single plot.

I currently have this...

```
names = list(test['type'].unique())
types = []
for name in names:
    single = df.loc[df.type == name]
    single = single.set_index(single.time, drop=False)
    single = single.resample("D")
    types.append(single)

for single, name in zip(types, names):
    single.rename(columns={"value":name}, inplace=True)

combined = pd.concat(types, axis=1)
combined.plot()
```

... resulting in the combined data frame containing the desired output and the following plot:
[image: What it should look like]

It seems to me that this could be achieved more easily by using `groupby` on the initial dataframe but so far I have not been able to reproduce the desired plot using this method.

What is "the smart way" to do this?

EDIT:
Bigger data sample (csv, 1000 rows) at: http://pastebin.com/gi16nZdh

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: Can you provide a bigger example data set? In a pastebin in csv format or such.

Comment: Added a 1k rows csv random sample from the data frame.

Comment: It certainly helped, thank you. I had to change `pivot`to `pivot_table`with the entire dataset but you certainly pointed out the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` easily to do what you want, I've created a random example DataFrame below and then used [`df.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) to arrange the table as wanted.

**Note: I've resampled as weekly as I only have one data value per type per day, don't forget to change this for your data.**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('2013-04-03', periods = 50, freq='D')
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(dict(time=dates, value=pd.np.random.randn(len(dates)), type=i)) for i in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
df = pd.concat(dfs)

pivoted = df.pivot(index='time', columns='type', values='value')

pivoted.resample('W')

print(pivoted.head(10))
# type               A         B         C         D
# time
# 2013-04-03  0.161839  0.509179  0.055078 -2.072243
# 2013-04-04  0.323308  0.891982 -1.266360  1.950389
# 2013-04-05 -2.542464 -0.441849 -2.686183  0.717737
# 2013-04-06  0.750871  0.438343 -0.002004  0.478821
# 2013-04-07 -0.118890  1.026121  1.283397 -1.306257
# 2013-04-08 -0.396373 -1.078925 -0.539617 -1.625549
# 2013-04-09  0.328076  1.964779  0.194198  0.232702
# 2013-04-10 -0.178683  0.177359  0.500873 -0.729988
# 2013-04-11  0.762800  1.576662 -0.456480  0.526162
# 2013-04-12 -1.301265 -0.586977 -0.903313  0.162008

pivoted.plot()

plt.show()
```

This code creates a pivot_table called `pivoted` where each of the columns are now `type` and the data is the index. We then simply resample it using `pivoted.resample('W')`.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: This solves the question for the small example. With the entire data the `df.pivot(...)` method failed because there were duplicate keys, i.e. several observations at the same point in time. However, `df.pivot_table(...)` works using the same arguments as you provided.